# How to get Handle of a form that hosts a COM-Control

Tags: .net, delphi, winapi, com, sendmessage

I have a visual DotNet-Control that I use as COM-Control in a Delphi project.
Now I want to get the handle of the delphi form that hosts this DotNet-component in DotNet. 
Sure - i could pass the Form's handle from Delphi to DotNet using something like a  setParentHandle(pHandle: hwnd); method that I define, but this is not the way I want to do it here.

Is there any Winapi call that can give me the handle of a component that I draw something on in DotNet?

I want to use this handle in order to send Messages that can not be handled by the DotNetComponent itself to the Delphi Form.

Comment: Can you be precise about what you have in your .net code. What class is your .net component derived from? That is the component that is hosted in your Delphi app.

Comment: the dotnet component is basically derived from UserControl. I use this as a container for a Chart-Component. However I can't access the hosting Delphi Form (actually I need just the handle) in my C# Code.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` or `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`?

Comment: When this Chart-Component of yours is created it probably creates its own window right? So why don't you simply check which window is parent of this window of yours? But what if your component doesn't create its own window? Then the handle to existing window has got to have been passed to it before so that it knows where should its contents be rendered to. So use that handle then.

Comment: @SilverWarior Probably? Depends critically on which framework is in use.

Comment: If all you want is the window handle of the parent, can't you just call [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the window handle of the control?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The most fitting answer is the one by Jim Mischel. Using GetParent of WinApi delivers the handle of the delphi component that hosts the DotNet-Component!

Comment: It's disappointing that you wouldn't let us know what your control was. I can't understand why you didn't tell us that information.

Comment: I use System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using the [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of WinApi just like this in C#.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){

    // 0x20a is the Message constant for WM_MOUSEWHEEL (Scrolling on your control)
    if(m.Msg == 0x20a){
      IntPtr hWnd= GetParent(this.Handle);
      SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
    }
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Remark: Forwarding all messages to the parent control will break your Control since it won't receive its own messages any longer.

Comment: This code will break your control since it won't receive its messages.

Comment: Oh thank you, you're right. In my productive code I prefilter the messages before sending them to the parent control e.g. using `if(m.Msg = 0x20a)`. However I need the GetParent method to get the handle of the parent window of my control.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when a host window contains a visual ActiveX control, the host implements the [`IOleClientSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693706.aspx) interface and passes that to the control via its [`IOleObject::SetClientSite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684013.aspx) implementation. The control can query that `IOleClientSite` for [`IOleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102.aspx) or [`IOleInPlaceSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686586.aspx) and call its `GetWindow()` method to get the host's HWND.

I don't know how `IOleObject` is implemented at the .NET layer, but this is how the COM/ActiveX layer works.  So there might be a way for a .NET control to override its own `SetClientSite()` method, or provide some other means, to access the host's `IOleClientSite` interface.